# why back pressure occurs with many output streams

Tags: apache-flink, kafka-consumer-api, backpressure

my flink job now has 60+ output streams, each stream's implementation is simple。But, why back pressure happens in kafka source operator.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXzP1.png)
my job graph

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcbop.png)
kafka source back pressure

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it's physically impossible for your job to run faster than the throughput of the slowest sink.